# Stop MacBook from using up the battery while it is in sleep mode

Tags: macos, bluetooth, battery, sleep

I have a MacBook Pro from 2019. I love that I can simply close it, so it goes to sleep - and bring it with me. But every now and then, I take it up from by bag - and then it's steaming hot and have it using up a good portion of the battery.

I'm not sure, what the real culprit-applications are, but my theory is:

1. **AirPods.** Sometimes I can put on my AirPods, and then they pair with my Macbook Pro, even though it's in my bag in sleep?!
2. **Watcher-programs (running in terminal).** I'm a web developer and run the `npm run watch`-command quite frequently. I wonder, if the battery-consumption is because this watcher can run, while in sleep-mode? Hmm...

---

### Solution Attempt 1: System settings

I tried going through the System Settings. But couldn't find anything.

### Solution attempt 2: Disallow Bluetooth-connections while in sleep

I tried Googling for, disallowing Bluetooth-connections while in sleep mode. I found this answer here: [Disable Bluetooth or disconnect Bluetooth connections when lid is closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365055/disable-bluetooth-or-disconnect-bluetooth-connections-when-lid-is-closed) - but I'm just baffled that I need some third party application to achieve this?

### Solution attempt 3: Which applications spent energy over the past 12 hours

In Activity Monitor, in the Energy-pane, there is a column called '12 hr Power'. I can try looking at that, after this happens, to see what drained the energy. Even though that it can be one application draining the energy, while it's another one that prevents the Mac from sleeping.

Last time it happened, it was 'Spotlight', that had 73% in that column.

### Solution attempt 4: Preventing sleep

There is a column in Activity Monitor called 'Preventing sleep':

[image: preventing sleep]

I'll keep an eye out of this.

I also discovered, that if I run the command: `pmset -g`, then it'll list services/daemons preventing sleep as well. Read more about this here: [How to see battery consumption per application (!!) over the past X hours on my MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452472)

### Solution attempt 5: `powermetric`

Apparently there is a `powermetric`-command (that I stumbled across here: [Energy impact from terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150623/220328)).

With this command:

```
sudo powermetrics -i 1000 --poweravg 1 | grep 'Average cumulatively decayed power score' -A 20
```

... you Mac can analyze power consumption. Pretty neat. I'm not sure how to use it here, though. Hmm..

Comment: If you can turn off Sleep options and use plain suspend so everything is off and not useable while suspended

Comment: Are you certain it slept? Activity Monitor, set to 'All Processes' then [in CPU or Memory tab] right click the header bar & add the 'Preventing Sleep' column. Click to sort to the top, then see what's listed. Some things like `hidd` wil say prevents sleep but will get out of the way when needed.

Comment: “If you can turn off Sleep options and use plain suspend so everything is off and not useable while suspended” What does this mean in the context of macOS? The only options that exist are “Sleep,” “Restart” and “Shutdown.” With macOS “Sleep” can be configured to do a deep sleep/hibernation. There is also a “Power Nap” option that is enabled by default that allows a MacBook to still do things like check for email and such while sleeping. But there is no “suspend.” I recommend the original poster to to “System Preferences > Battery” and then click the “Battery” option and disable “Power Nap.”

Comment: I updated the question with further attempts and info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it said the TuneIn app was causing coreaudiod to prevent sleep. Check that it is off. “pmset -g” can tell a lot! Also, add the “PreventingSleep” column to Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unplug USB devices
   USB devices that draw power from your Mac may continue to use your Mac power while it’s asleep. For example, a USB transceiver for a mouse or external keyboard that remained connected to the device and plugged into your MacBook will drain your battery. The only way to stop this is to unplug the device.
2. Check your Mac for unnecessary background processes
   One possible reason for your MacBook battery draining while it sleeps is processes running in the background you know nothing about. These are often initiated by login items. Login items are applications that get automatically opened when you log in. They can consume a lot of CPU resources and Mac energy.
3. Turn off Power Nap
   Power Nap is a feature of macOS that allows your MacBook to continue checking for new emails as well as Calendar and other iCloud updates. However, to do that, it has to connect to iCloud, which means using battery power. So, if you want to reduce or eliminate the drain on the battery while your Mac sleeps, you’ll need to turn Power Nap off.

Comment: Jenny, thanks for your answer, but I experienced the same issue a few times, but my power nap is off and background processes should pause when the lid is closed. No devices were connected, so I doubt this answer will help in the @Zeth's case.